# Moving an object downwards, C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button press that moves an object upwards. I'm just wanting to know what I have to change to make it move downwards (Different button)

```
private void CP_GFButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (LDoor.Location.Y < 0)
                while (Rdoor.Location.Y < 0)
                {
                    LDoor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(LDoor.Location.X, LDoor.Location.Y - 1);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

                    Rdoor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Rdoor.Location.X, Rdoor.Location.Y - 1);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
        }
```

Comment: If subtracting from `Y` makes it go up, then adding to `Y` should make it go down, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        while (LDoor.Location.Y < MaxVal)
            while (Rdoor.Location.Y < MaxVal)
            {
                LDoor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(LDoor.Location.X, LDoor.Location.Y + 1);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

                Rdoor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Rdoor.Location.X, Rdoor.Location.Y + 1);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
```

Comment: This helped quite a lot. Do you have any idea how I can make the doors move open and sort of close in on themselves by any chance?